# Peugeot 207 depollution fault

Tags: peugeot

I have a 2008 Peugeot 207, 1.6 Turbo and lately the depollution system is faulty - the check engine sign lit. The car still has the power of a 1.6 engine but the turbo is not working.

One mechanic told me to remove the CAT and the problem will be fixed, but when I asked another mechanic he told me that if I remove the CAT the engine will be at risk of breaking and in few weeks i would need a new engine.

What should i do? Has anyone removed the cat and encountered a engine problem?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I take it a code popped and was read due to observing the check engine light. Do you know what exactly the code is which popped? It would be P0xx ... This would help tremendously with which approach to take to fix your vehicle.

Comment: ok @Paulster2 tomorrow i ll see what code it is and let you know,, anyhow do u think it's risky to remove the cat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While deleting the catalytic converter ("cat") will not "break the engine", it is *extremely* unlikely that removing the system will cure the check engine light.

The description of the code will give a clue as to what the correct course of action should be. Possibilities include:

- a clogged catalytic converter that should be replaced (not removed altogether!)
- replacing an ageing O2 sensor
- reconnecting a disconnected O2 sensor

---

To reiterate, the description of the specific error code(s) should help narrow down the list of possible culprits.

Answer (score 1):

You can get then regenerated  aka "cleaned out" if you go to a diesel specialist. Manager of a Kwik Fit told me they used to "just replace them" (c £350) but now tell clients that they can get them regenerated for around £80

also a long fast drive where the car gets very hot will clear it out to some extent.

[link to site detailing steps to force your own regenaration](http://www.eurocats.co.uk/2011/07/02/the-next-regeneration-how-to-perform-a-forced-regeneration/)

Answer (score 0):

try to add in the fuel tank a liquid that is going through all the mixture of air-fuel route. That means, is going through the fuel pump, fuel filter, turbo, injectors, lambda sensor, O2 sensor and catalytic converter. If any dirty item is on these sections will normally be removed.

Automotive - Motorsport Engineer

Answer (score 0):

have many years my Peugeot 207CC replaced many tires and rims... live in mexico Bumpy roads. But ¨depollution system faulty¨is bothering me for several months. I believe I found the solution after reading about it on internet. Looked for Cataclean from Halford. Not available but I used Hi-Gear EZ emissions pass & catalyctic converter cleaner from Propower made in Hudson USA. and after 4 km it worked. Car is running well and powerfull.  Hope it stays like this. They recommend to add  Propower after 3000 miles 5000 km.

Answer (score -1):

I have used redex for the engine management light before and it works, also for the depollution system fault